# Como passar um vetor de struct por parâmetro de referencia?

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, ponteiro, array

Minha dúvida é, qual o erro dessa passagem? Parece que a passagem `(*dadosCliente+i)` está incorreta, alguém sabe o porque?

```
struct cliente{
    char nome[50];
    char endereco[50];
}

void addCliente(struct cliente *dadosCliente, int *i){
    printf("qual o nome do cliente?");
    scanf(" %s", (*dadosCliente+i).nome);
    printf("qual o endereço do cliente?");
    scanf(" %s", (*dadosCliente+i).endereco);
    *i=*i+1;
}

void main(){
    int i=0,h=0;
    struct cliente clientes[1000];
    while(h!=1){
        printf("Caso queira sair do cadastro digite 1");
        addCliente(clientes, &i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Pode ser mais específico? O que você esperava que acontecesse que não está acontecendo?

Comment: O (*dadosCliente+i) parece estar incorreto.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português, nós somos um site de perguntas e resposta. Para podermos responder melhor sua pergunta, teria como aprimorar um pouco mais a sua dúvida?

Comment: Dei uma editada.

Comment: Quando for fazer uma pergunta sobre um erro, lembre-se de dizer exatamente qual é o erro. Se o comportamento é inesperado, diga o que esperava e o que obteu. Se houve erro de compilação (provavelmente seu caso), informe a mensagem de diagnóstico.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Primeiramente você precisa derreferenciar o `i`. Depois disso vai ser necessário mais um par de parênteses:

```
(*(dadosCliente+*i)).endereco
```

ou ainda

```
(dadosCliente+*i)->endereco
```

Comment: Vale acrescentar que é um `scanf`, logo teria que ter um endereço ali, ou seja, ou remove o `*` ou adiciona `&` antes do nome da variável.

Comment: Neste caso não, porque o endereço e nome são arrays

Comment: Verdade, não tinha notado isso.

Answer (score 1):

```
(scanf(" %s", (*dadosCliente+i).nome);
```

As alterações precisariam ser essas:

```
(scanf(" %s", (dadosCliente+*i)->nome);
```

Você desreferencia o ponteiro `i` e depois soma ao primeiro endereço de `dadosCliente`, que desreferência-se com `->` e acessa o campo nome. Como o campo nome é uma vetor, só é preciso `nome`, o primeiro endereço, para guardar a string, mas você poderia ser redundante:

```
(scanf(" %s", &( (dadosCliente+*i)->(*nome) ));
```

Há alguns graves problemas no seu código...

1. Looping sem fim, nunca haverá mudança no valor de h
2. O printf só escaneará até o primeiro espaço em branco, o resto ficará no buffer repondendo perguntas subsequentes
3. Invasões de memória no campo nome e no vetor cliente; O primeiro devido o printf estar sem limitações, precisaria algo como: `printf(" %50[^\n]s", vetChar)`; O segundo devido ao looping sem fim

[Aqui](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) há um material de estudo sobre o printf.

Espero ter ajudado. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
struct cliente{
    char nome[50];
    char endereco[50];
};//faltava o ponto e virgula

void addCliente(struct cliente *dadosCliente, int *i)//ha duas maneiras de usar o vetor de struct por referencia
{
    printf("qual o nome do cliente?");
    scanf(" %s", dadosCliente->nome);//a primeira muito mais simples
    printf("qual o endereço do cliente?");
    scanf(" %s", (*(dadosCliente+*i)).endereco);// e aqui no caso pra poder dar certo oq pretendia fazer 
    *i++;
}

void main(){
    int i=0,h=0;
    struct cliente clientes[1000];
    while(h!=1){
        printf("Caso queira sair do cadastro digite 1");
        addCliente(clientes, &i);
    }
}
```